# how to determine development rate table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to determine the ratio of animals to reach a stage of their development in a certain amount of time in days. I have the days at which the animals are reaching that developmental stage.

```
X<-filter(sort_delays, Treatment=="Control")%>%select('W-L5')
```

This is `X`:

```
X <- data.frame(W.L5 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
     7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L))
```

Then I created a data frame with the columns I need, one containing the different days at which my animals may develop and other ones to input data needed to calculate the ratio

```
Days<-c(4:9) 
number<-NA
Percent<-NA
Total_percent<-NA
df<-data.frame(Days, number, Percent, Total_percent)
```

then I populated my data frame using the following code:

```
#now start populating the number column
df[1,2]<- length(which(X==df[1,1]))
df[2,2]<- length(which(X==df[2,1]))
df[3,2]<- length(which(X==df[3,1]))
df[4,2]<- length(which(X==df[4,1]))
df[5,2]<- length(which(X==df[5,1]))
df[6,2]<- length(which(X==df[6,1]))

#use number to figure out percent
df$Percent<-(df$number/length(X[,1]))*100

#use percent to determine the total percentage
df[1,4]<- df[1,3]
df[2,4]<- df[2,3]+df[1,4]
df[3,4]<- df[3,3]+df[2,4]
df[4,4]<- df[4,3]+df[3,4]
df[5,4]<- df[5,3]+df[4,4]
df[5,4]<- df[6,3]+df[5,4]
```

the resulting `df` then looks like this:

```
Days number Percent Total_percent
1    4      0       0             0
2    5      5      20            20
3    6     17      68            88
4    7      3      12           100
5    8      0       0           100
6    9      0       0           100
```

even though this has worked just fine to create the table I want, I will eventually be working with bigger data sets and more variation in the days, resulting in more rows in my 'df' thus resulting in enormous chunks of code.

I was wondering  if anyone knows of a better way to do this?

Comment: `#use percent to determine the total percentage` can be done like this: `df[,4] <- cumsum(df[,3])`

Comment: `#now start populating the number column` this can be done: `df[,2] <- lapply(df[,1], function(y) length(which(X==y)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have `sort_delays` but considering `X` the right output then:

```
X<-filter(sort_delays, Treatment=="Control")%>%select('W-L5')

df<-data.frame(Days=c(4:9))

df$number <- unlist(lapply(df$Days, function(y) length(which(X==y))))

df$Percent<-(df$number/length(X[,1]))*100                 

df$Total_percent <- cumsum(df$Percent)
```

This will give the desired outcome:

```
df
##   Days number Percent Total_percent
## 1    4      0       0             0
## 2    5      5      20            20
## 3    6     17      68            88
## 4    7      3      12           100
## 5    8      0       0           100
## 6    9      0       0           100
```